# flutter dart add convert a query string to a map

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to add the params query string to the queryParameters map.

```
_params = "from=2021-04-10&to=2021-05-20";
// or like
_params = "var1=abc&var2=123";


Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {
  'token': _token.toString(),
  'page': _page.toString(),
};

final response = await http.get(
  Uri.https('www.domain.com', 'api/visits/index.json', queryParameters),
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
);
```

Should be:

```
Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {
  'token': _token.toString(),
  'domain_id': domain.id.toString(),
  'from': '2021-04-10',
  'to': '2021-05-20',
  // .... any variable from _params...
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have an encoded query string:

```dart
var _params = "from=2021-04-10&to=2021-05-20";
```

and are trying to parse it into a `Map<String, String>`, then you can use [`Uri.splitQueryString`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/splitQueryString.html):

```dart
var parsedQueryParameters = Uri.splitQueryString(_params);
```

Unlike manually parsing by tokenizing on `&` and `=` characters, `Uri.splitQueryString` also will decode escaped characters.

If you need to merge that into an existing `Map<String, String>` of query parameters, then you can use [`Map.addAll`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/addAll.html):

```dart
queryParameters.addAll(Uri.splitQueryString(_params));
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to split your queryString

```
String params = 'from=2021-04-10&to=2021-05-20';

Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {
  'token': _token.toString(),
  'page': _page.toString(),
};

params.split("&").forEach((item) { // Split with & first to get each key value pair
  var param = item.split('=');  // Split with = to get the key and value
  queryParameters[param[0]] = param[1];
});
```